# Seeing odd behavior when learning SpringAOP using @AspectJ style

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

Iam a new bee to Spring Framework and i am referring to documentation available with spring projects.

In the process i am also learning a new concept AOP. 
I am following the spring documentation to try out some samples
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

I tried to use "@AspectJ" style for my first Aspect Helloworld using Spring AOP.

This is my context config file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

     <aop:aspectj-autoproxy expose-proxy="false" />

    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

    <bean id="aoProgrammingAspectJ" class = "com.AOProgramming.AOProgrammingAspectJ">
    </bean>


    <bean id="aoProgrammingImpl" class = "com.AOProgramming.AOProgrammingImpl">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This is a simple interface

```
package com.AOProgramming;

public interface AOProgrammingInterface {

    public void startAspecting();

}
```

I implement this interface

```
package com.AOProgramming;

public class AOProgrammingImpl implements AOProgrammingInterface {


    @Override
    public void startAspecting() {

        System.out.println("THe Aspecting has just begun for :");

    }
}
```

This is where i am defining the aspect definition for pointcut and advice

```
package com.AOProgramming;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;


@Aspect
public class AOProgrammingAspectJ {

    @Pointcut("execution( * com.AOProgramming.*.*(..))")
    public void cuttingOne() {}

    @Before("cuttingOne()")
    public void adviceCuttingOne1(){

        System.out.println("This is the at the beginning");

    }



}
```

This is my actual INVOKER class

```
package com.AOProgramming;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class AOProgrammingInvokerApp {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("AOProgramming-servlet.xml");

        AOProgrammingImpl obj = (AOProgrammingImpl) context.getBean("aoProgrammingImpl");

        obj.startAspecting();

    }

}
```

When i tried to execute the sample  i am getting the following Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6 cannot be cast to com.AOProgramming.AOProgrammingImpl
    at com.AOProgramming.AOProgrammingInvokerApp.main(AOProgrammingInvokerApp.java:12)
```

I am trying to re-read the complete page still i have the same issue also not getting enough material dealing with latest Spring AOP samples. All pre-dates to 2002 or 2008 which has different way of explaining SpringAOP.

Can someone help me to understand what i missed here

Appreciate your help

Comment: The actual type of the Spring bean (and of its proxy) is AOProgrammingInterface. That's the type you should use when getting the bean from the context and using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this you need to understand how [JDK proxies work and what their limitations are (and the alternative, CGLIB proxies)](http://insufficientinformation.blogspot.ca/2007/12/spring-dynamic-proxies-vs-cglib-proxies.html). In short, JDK proxies only keep the type of your target bean's interfaces. So the proxy generated for `AOProgrammingImpl` will be of type `AOProgrammingInterface` but not `AOProgrammingImpl` even though the target is of type `AOProgrammingImpl`.

You can change this

```
AOProgrammingImpl obj = (AOProgrammingImpl) context.getBean("aoProgrammingImpl");
```

to this

```
AOProgrammingInterface obj = (AOProgrammingInterface) context.getBean("aoProgrammingImpl");
```

Or you can add CGLIB to your classpath and change your config to

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy expose-proxy="false" proxy-target-class="true" />
```

so that Spring uses CGLIB proxies which work with class type.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes sense now to me what i missed in understanding the concept of AOP. thanks for sharing the link about Proxy. Honestly lots of learning...

Comment: @linux It will all be worth it soon enough :)

Comment: I have a question (pardon if its dumb), what if my class implements two interfaces? which one  i should cast it to?

Comment: @linux If your class implements two interfaces, then the proxy will also implement both those interfaces. You can cast to whichever you need. If you need to call method `m1()` declared in `FirstInterface`, then you need to cast it to a `FirstInterface`.

Comment: Okay!! i asked this question not really thinking any real use-case but more on understanding proxy.Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: @linux You might be interested in [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html) which goes in depth about JDK proxies (it's a Oracle article).